# 500 internal error after turncate system table

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

I am getting an error:

> Blockquote
>   HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

The last thing I did was I emptied the system table in drupal.

Below is my log. Please advice what I can do to get it up again.

> Blockquote
>   Failed loading /usr/lib/php5//xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5//xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   Failed loading /usr/lib/php5//xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5//xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:56:09 2013] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
>   Failed loading /usr/lib/php5//xdebug.so:  /usr/lib/php5//xdebug.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:56:53 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.6-1ubuntu1.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user_access() in /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc on $
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/iqacademy/index.php:0
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. menu_execute_active_handler() /var/www/iqacademy/index.php:17
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   3. menu_get_item() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:344
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   4. _menu_translate() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:317
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:00 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   5. _menu_check_access() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:582
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user_access() in /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc on $
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/iqacademy/index.php:0
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. menu_execute_active_handler() /var/www/iqacademy/index.php:17
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   3. menu_get_item() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:344
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   4. _menu_translate() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:317
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:03 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   5. _menu_check_access() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:582
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:04 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function user_access() in /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc on $
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/iqacademy/index.php:0
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. menu_execute_active_handler() /var/www/iqacademy/index.php:17
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   3. menu_get_item() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:344
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   4. _menu_translate() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:317
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   5. _menu_check_access() /var/www/iqacademy/includes/menu.inc:582
>   
> [Tue Jul 30 13:59:08 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico

Comment: https://drupal.org/node/26256 - Drupal uses the database to track local filesystem locations of certain required modules. Which is a *terrible* design, but that's another story. You will need to put the correct entries back into the database.

Comment: @DaveRandom u are right . I got it working after putting the values back in